# Case when for a particular column in first table based on column values in second table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case

I am trying to crack the following problem with SQL on Snowflake, but I kept running into problems when trying to use `case when [condition] is null then...`. The problem I am encountering is as follows: I have two tables `A` and `B`, where `A` has column `Market_ID`, `House_ID` , `Revenue` and `B` has column `Market_ID`, `House_ID`, `Date` where `Date` has the format YYYY-MM-DD (e.g. 2022-08-01). Now, I am trying to join these two tables based on the following rule: if the `Date` column in Table B is **above** a fixed threshold (say, 2022-01-15), we select `Market_ID` from Table A and `House_ID` from either Table A or Table B depending on the last date that is lower than the fixed threshold. If the `Date` column in Table B is **less** than certain value, then we select `Market_ID` from Table A and set `House_ID` to be NaN. In any case, the end goal is to cover all the `Market_ID` and `House_ID` in Table A, while Table B is playing the role of `conditional filter` more or less.

Sample Data

```
Table A    Market_ID   House_ID    Revenue
        1  14023       125         80.24
        2  14050       128         91.25
        3  14101       196         150.25
        4  15005       197         160.5
        5  15516       189         120.3
        6  15212       600         69.5
        7  14115       209         88.2
      
Table B    Market_ID   House_ID    Date
        1  14023       125         2021-11-12
        2  14050       223         2022-05-22
        3  14101       151         2022-07-15
        4  14101       196         2021-03-21
        5  15005       189         2022-06-22
        6  15005       595         2022-11-18
        7  15516       209         2021-06-13
        8  15516       313         2021-05-15
        9  15212       595         2021-12-25
       10  15212       600         2022-03-05
       11  14115       300         2022-05-07
       12  14115       209         2022-10-06
```

**Expected output.** Given a *fixed* date, like **2022-01-15**, then I would like to have the following output, as a result of the SQL Query:

```
               Market_ID   House_ID    
            1  14023       NaN -- since 2022-01-15 > 2021-11-12         
            2  14050       223 -- since 2022-01-15 < 2022-05-22        
            3  14101       151 -- since 2022-01-15 < 2022-07-15          
            4  15005       595 -- since 2022-01-15 < max(2022-11-18, 2022-06-22)        
            5  15516       NaN -- since 2022-01-15 > max(2021-06-13, 2021-05-15)         
            6  15212       600 -- since 2022-01-15 < 2022-03-05        
            7  14115       209 -- since 2022-01-15 < 2022-10-06
```

**Question.** Could anyone please help me achieve the above goal with `case when` statement? I tried using

```
case a.House_ID
  when b.Date > [some condition here] then b.House_ID
  else NULL
end as House_ID
from Table A a
left join Table B b
on a.market_id = b.market_id`
```

But it did not give me the expected output.

**Question 2.** What if Table A has a separate column called 'Date_from' and the rule of deciding on `House_ID` is changed based on whether 'Date_from' in Table A is less than 'Date' in Table B for **each** Market_ID. So, how to achieve the same goal above if Table A is like

```
Table A    Market_ID   House_ID    Revenue   Date
        1  14023       125         80.24     2022-02-15
        2  14050       128         91.25     2021-05-16
        3  14101       196         150.25    2022-07-03
        4  15005       197         160.5     2022-09-12
        5  15516       189         120.3     2021-10-15
        6  15212       600         69.5      2021-12-05
        7  14115       209         88.2      2022-08-20
```

**Expected Output.**

```
           Market_ID   House_ID   
        1  14023       NaN         
        2  14050       223         
        3  14101       151        
        4  15005       595        
        5  15516       209         
        6  15212       600         
        7  14115       NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this one can help you:

```
select
a.Market_ID, 
b.House_ID
from TableA a
left join TableB b
on a.market_id = b.market_id
and b.Date > '2022-01-15'
qualify row_number() over (partition by a.House_ID order by Date DESC) = 1
order by a.Market_ID; 

+-----------+----------+
| MARKET_ID | HOUSE_ID |
+-----------+----------+
|     14023 | NULL     |
|     14050 | 223      |
|     14101 | 151      |
|     14115 | 209      |
|     15005 | 595      |
|     15212 | 600      |
|     15516 | NULL     |
+-----------+----------+
```

For question 2:

```
select
a.Market_ID, 
b.House_ID
from TableA a
left join TableB b
on a.market_id = b.market_id
and b.Date > a.Date_From
qualify row_number() over (partition by a.House_ID order by b.Date DESC) = 1
order by a.Market_ID; 

+-----------+----------+
| MARKET_ID | HOUSE_ID |
+-----------+----------+
|     14023 | NULL     |
|     14050 | 223      |
|     14101 | 151      |
|     14115 | 209      |
|     15005 | 595      |
|     15212 | 600      |
|     15516 | NULL     |
+-----------+----------+
```

Can you check your output? I don't understand why 15212 has 600, although 14101 returns NULL. 14101 has two dates: 2022-07-15 and 2021-03-21, so it should return 151.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I added an extension part of the original question a bit. Could you please kindly help?

Comment: @user177196 I think you wanted to comment on the correct answer (Aksjay's)?

Comment: I haven't tested it out, so I wasn't sure if it is correct. Could you kindly help with the extension question?

Comment: @user177196 can you check my latest query?

Comment: I checked the output, and the reason 1521 has 600 is because its corresponding date 2021-12-05 < max(2021-12-25, 2022-03-05) and so we pick the latest entry in Table B. Does it make sense? 14101 should return 151, you are correct, thank you. I corrected it. But I am not sure what does `qualify row_number() ` does (I know it is a window function, but why did you apply it onto Table B)?

Comment: Also, how can we get the return value of NULL from your query, if the Market_ID does not appear on Table B (so basically, the LEFT JOIN condition is not satisfied on certain fixed date)?

Comment: your query with the line `qualify row_number() over...` doesn't work on Snowflake unfortunately ;p

Comment: They surely do because I do my all tests in Snowflake, and the results are also produced on Snowflake. Actually, I don't have any other databases :) Pls be careful how I used QUALIFY - it's at the end, and there is no WHERE clause etc....

Comment: I got you. I need to have the WHERE clause as well, so I need to modify your query a little bit. It worked out beautifully :) Thank you so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247191/discussion-between-user177196-and-gokhan-atil).

Answer (score 0):

try this statement

`select case when a.create_date > 1905-05-31 then a.create_date else NULL end  from test1 a  left join test2 b on a.id=b.id`

Comment: You need to quote 1905-05-31 otherwise dashs wil be seen as minus arithmetic operator.